# Why is my other list getting modified after copying from the first list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, reference, pass-by-reference

I was trying to format the graph `paths` to a series of all possible paths stored as nested lists

initially i wrote one solution with two for loops then i decided to make it into a single list comprehension when i came across this issue. My second list `comper` keeps getting operated on and modified even though i copied it from `comp`

i even printed out the id's and compared the objects, python says they're not referencing the same object, but when i carry out any operation on `comp` , `comper` is also affected.

I understand that python lists are passed by reference so they have to be copied if you want a fresh new copy to work on, but why is this happening?, i don't think it's a bug because I've copied lists so many times without this behaviour

```
paths = {
         'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['D'],
         'C': ['E']
         }

comp = [[key, i] for key in sorted(paths, key = None) for i in paths.get(key) if isinstance(paths.get(key), list)]
print(comp, 'this is the original comp')

comper = comp[:] # tried to copy the contents of comp into comper even tried list(comp), still get the same result
print(comper, 'comper copied, is unchanged')

if comp is comper:
    print('yes')
else:
    print(id(comp), id(comper))

for count, ele in enumerate(comp):
    for other in comp:
        if ele[-1] == other[0]:
            comp[count].append(other[-1])
            comp.remove(other)
            # comper.remove(other) fixes the problem but why is comper getting modified even when id's are different       

print(comper, 'apparently comper has changed because the operation was carried out on both')
print(comp)

print(id(comp), id(comper))
```

This is the output i get

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'E']] this is the original comp
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'E']] comper copied, is unchanged
139810664953992 139810664953288
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'E']] apparently comper has changed because the operation was carried out on both
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'E']]
139810664953992 139810664953288
```

comper has the extra elements because they were not removed from the list, if i uncomment the line that removes the other lists from `comper` then i basically get the same result

i even printed out the id's at the bottom and they're still different

Comment: import copy; comper = copy.copy(comp);

Comment: @Prune tried that it didn't work....comper is still getting modified

Comment: You need to `deepcopy` since you're dealing with nested lists.

Comment: You copy the references to the small lists. Either use `map` to copy all small lists and make a new one from the copies, or use `deepcopy`.

Comment: Thanks all. there was even an answer that explained why nested lists get modified when they are shallow copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import copy
Comper = copy.deepcopy(comp)
```